Ubuntu Server 23.10 and 24.03 installation on a Mac mini 2018 crashs
I'm trying to recycle an Intel Mac Mini 2018 into a home server.
I've followed some instruction to install Ubuntu Server but subiquity is crashing every time after the disk configuration.
I haven't found any -b option to prevent to try to install the GRUB boot manager on subiquity.
Do I have to switch on Ubuntu Desktop for such hardware or there is a way to install Ubuntu Server ?

Try installing Ubuntu desktop. Later you can turn off loading the GUI. But installing Ubuntu desktop may help with debugging the installation errors.

I've just tried with the Desktop I can go in the try mode, all is well, but the issue is the same during the install even with a ubiquity -b

Does the desktop installer show any error?

Yes same crash, I'm trying to use the whole Mac disk and not just only the partitions for / and swap now

ok, if I use the whole disk it works...,

I am also trying  install ubuntu 24.04 on the internal SSD of a mac mini 2018. I followed this process but ended up with the crash the following crash error .
To get here I booted with "try or install ubuntu". Then I went to the terminal, I runned ubiquity -b (which before I had to install with sudo apt-get install ubiquity). After, I selected the FAT32 partition I previously created and tried to install Ubuntu but got the message shown in the image above.
This is how the partitions looked. I selected  te Fat32 partition as Et4 Journaling and mount point / as the following image shows: 
Anyone successfully installed Ubuntu 24.04 in the internal SSD of a mac mini 2018?
